# Is it possible to generate Ampere's force between the superconductor and the current-carrying wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, superconductivity

In superconducting state, There is a current-carrying wire between the superconductor and the magnet，Is it possible to generate Ampere's force  between the superconductor and the current-carrying wire?

[image]